# Set 1 second timeout on navigation buttons

Tags: javascript, delay, settimeout

I have a slider navigation on my (cms) site, the links in that navigation need to load the URL after 1 second.

The navigation now looks some like this:

```
<div class="slides">
  <div class="slideItem"><a href="page1.html">link1</a></div>
  <div class="slideItem"><a href="page2.html">link2</a></div>
  <div class="slideItem"><a href="page3.html">link3</a></div>
</div>
```

Can this below script I found be used in the a href somehow? (if this works).

```
setTimeout( "window.location.href = 'http://domain.com/url.html'", 5*1000 );
```

Answer (score 0):

this will redirect user to http://domain.com/url.html after 5 seconds

```
setTimeout( "window.location.href = 'http://domain.com/url.html'", 5*1000 );
```

if you want 1 sec delay use 1000 as second param,
have you checked this script at all ?
what you want to achieve ??

Comment: oh sorry for answer delay lol. I would like to have something like: <a href="url.html" javascript(this.link.1sec.delay)>Link</a>. That would be the best way because I use some CMS and rather use this inline somehow if possible.